# How to remove all contents of a directory using Golang?

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and can't seem to find a way to delete all the contents of a directory when I don't know the contents.

I've tried:

```
os.RemoveAll("/tmp/*")
os.Remove("/tmp/*")
```

but get `remove *: no such file or directory` or `invalid argument`.

And of course if you do:

```
os.RemoveAll("/tmp/")
```

it deletes the `tmp` directory as well. Which is not what I want.

Comment: Ofc you use shell-commands to do that and call os.Exec.

Comment: @0x434D53: Shell commands are OS and shell dependent. Use Go package `os` OS and shell independent functions for portability. For example, I tested my Go solution on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Ofc they are. Was just an additional suggestion that might fit his usecase. Had a reason i did not write it as an answer.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Write a simple `RemoveContents` function. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func RemoveContents(dir string) error {
    d, err := os.Open(dir)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer d.Close()
    names, err := d.Readdirnames(-1)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, name := range names {
        err = os.RemoveAll(filepath.Join(dir, name))
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    dir := strings.TrimSuffix(filepath.Base(os.Args[0]), filepath.Ext(os.Args[0]))
    dir = filepath.Join(os.TempDir(), dir)
    dirs := filepath.Join(dir, `tmpdir`)
    err := os.MkdirAll(dirs, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    file := filepath.Join(dir, `tmpfile`)
    f, err := os.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    f.Close()
    file = filepath.Join(dirs, `tmpfile`)
    f, err = os.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    f.Close()

    err = RemoveContents(dir)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, I have actually gone with something similar but using `ioutil.ReadDir` to save opening the dir. Thanks

Comment: @mattl: That's not good. For package `os`, "[Readdirnames](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames) reads and returns a slice of names from the directory." For package `ioutil`, "[ReadDir](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir) reads the directory named by dirname and returns a list of sorted directory entries." Switching from `os` to `ioutil`, you added an unnecessary sort of the name list: [`func ReadDir`](https://golang.org/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go):  `sort.Sort(byName(list))`.

Answer (score 149):

Simply do:

```
os.RemoveAll("/tmp/")
os.MkdirAll("/tmp/",FileMode)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, either it didn't exist when this question was raised or it does something unexpected.

Comment: It most probably existed as he talked about removeall , so it might do something unexpected, but I'd like to know what as I use this method pretty often

Comment: @Lomithrani RemoveAll says that it exits on the first encounter of an error. Individually removing each file would allow you to remove more in a case where multiple errors would be expected. That's all I could come up with after reading the documentation.

Comment: oh hang on, I think we were trying to delete the contents of a directory but not the directory itself. As I said at the bottom of my question removeAll removes the parent directory as well. Making the directory again would work but would need to match the current permissions set on it.

Comment: This won't work if you don't have permission to remove `/tmp`.

Comment: You must perform a Stat first to retrieve the dirs permissions and later use those to correctly create the dir again. And as @aioobe pointed out, does not work if you have no perm on the dir itself

Comment: if we speak about /tmp/ it can be a mount point, or it can be in use by other processes

Answer (score 29):

Just use `ioutil.ReadDir` to get a slice of `os.FileInfo` types, *then* iterate through and remove each child item using `os.RemoveAll`.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    dir, err := ioutil.ReadDir("/tmp")
    for _, d := range dir {
        os.RemoveAll(path.Join([]string{"tmp", d.Name()}...))
    }
}
```

That way, you are removing only all the child items and **not** the parent `/tmp` folder itself.

I have used this pattern many times before (e.g. test logs, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

You could use `filepath.Glob()` to get a slice of the contents of the folder, then delete everything it returns. This allows you to use `/tmp/*` to indicate what you want to delete, and could also be used to delete `/tmp/*.go`, or `/tmp/*/*.go`, etc.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func RemoveGlob(path string) (err error) {
    contents, err := filepath.Glob(path)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for _, item := range contents {
        err = os.RemoveAll(item)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
    return
}    

func main() {
    err := RemoveGlob("/tmp/*")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error removing files: %+v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the most simple and efficient approach to what was asked

Answer (score 3):

```
func RemoveContents(dir string) error {
    files, err := filepath.Glob(filepath.Join(dir, "*"))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        err = os.RemoveAll(file)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: No good. Pattern `*` doesn't match hidden files (names starting with a dot, like `.config.yaml` for example). OP asked to delete all teh contents of a directory.

Comment: This works perfectly as intended. It deletes all the contents of a directory including hidden files.