# Why can my Go program not remove files?

Tags: go

I wrote a Go program that listens to a http request:

```
server := http.Server{
    Addr:        "0.0.0.0:65534",
    Handler:     &MyHandler{},
    ReadTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
}
server.ListenAndServe()
```

I set browser request "/exit"  mapping to a function:

```
func exit(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    DeleteCache("../upload")
    defer os.Exit(0)
}
```

I want to delete the files inside folder  "../upload", and my DeleteCache function looks like this:

```
func deletefile(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if path == "../upload" {
        return nil
    }
    err1 := os.Remove(path)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err1)
        return err1
    }
    return err1
}

func DeleteCache(dirName string) {
    err := filepath.Walk(dirName, deletefile)
    checkNil(err)
}
```

Next, I wrote test code like this:

```
func TestDeleteFile(t *testing.T) {
    //service is a package name.
    service.DeleteCache("../upload")
}
```

The test code can run very well, it deleted all of the files inside folder "../upload"

But when I ran the program fully, then opened  browser access "0.0.0.0:65534/exit", the program tells me

> remove ../upload: directory not empty

other URLs could run well, except "/exit" and it's handler function named "exit"

I guess the reason is conflict between the "go http listing service" and the "filepath.Walk", they can't run at the same time. Maybe I should run it use goroutines.

I would greatly appreciate a reply.

Comment: not sure, but, when you `walk` the dirs, aren't you attempting to delete the parents first? You may want to delete the deepest files/dirs first, then the parents.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450980/golang-remove-all-contents-of-a-directory

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I updated function "deletefile", to except the parents.But does not work.

Comment: @Amd thanks !  It work to me.

Comment: the `defer` is unnecessary in your exit handlerfunc

Comment: @Chief thanks very much~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `os.RemoveAll("../upload")`:

```
func RemoveAll(path string) error
```

> ```
> // RemoveAll removes path and any children it contains.
> // It removes everything it can but returns the first error
> // it encounters. If the path does not exist, RemoveAll
> // returns nil (no error).
> ```